# Can I refer to a node using a short name in DOT

Tags: graphviz, pandoc, dot

I'm trying to respresent a binary tree with GraphViz using DOT, can I have a longer text string as a node's text but them just refer to it using a shortname when linking it?
I'm working with GraphViz through Pandoc and Pandoc-plot.

I've tried setting and node's ID, name, label and refering to it but it just doesn't work. In my document it just got the codeblock instead a rendered graph, I've tested it with a simple graph and it renders fine.

I've tried a graph like this in the GraphViz online editor and the node's with the long names don't get connected in the right way.

```
graph {
   "Adam \n 01/01"[id="adam"]
   "Bella \n01/02"[id="bella"]
   "Eloise \n01/05"
   
   adam -- bella
   bella -- eloise
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you mix up node names and node labels (by default the node name is equal to the node label, so in your case the node name is `"Adam \n 01/01"` and also the label is `"Adam \n 01/01"` so you have to refer to it like:

```
"Adam \n 01/01" -- "Bella \n01/02"
```

but this is quite cumbersome and error prone so looks like you are looking for (as indicated bu "short names" request):

```
graph {
   adam [label="Adam \n 01/01"]
   bella [label="Bella \n01/02"]
   eloise [label ="Eloise \n01/05"]
   
   adam -- bella
   bella -- eloise
}
```